# devise_invitable: Prompt to set password after accepting invitation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-invitable

I have a Rails app in which one type of user may invite another to create an account by means of `devise_invitable.` I'm sending the invitation email, and when the invitee follows the link, I'd like them to enter some information, click 'submit', and then prompt them to create a password.

The invitation mechanism is working fine, and when the invitee enters their information, it is saved to their profile, and the invitation is marked as accepted, as I wanted. However, I don't know how to redirect the user to a new password page after they accept the invite. I set up an `after_accept_path_for` method in the ApplicationController, but I can't get it to go to my new page. (My new page is a form with `password` and `password_confirmation` fields). It's essentially a custom 'edit user' page with just those fields.

How do I get `devise_invitable` to redirect to this new form page?